# CGContext - is there a way to reset the current context

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

In my iPhone project, I've got a UIView where I implement the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Inside the method I do a whole bunch of drawing of lines, images and texts using this context. The problem is that when I re-use this view, the context does not get reset. Is there a method I can call to reset the context somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the context"?

Comment: I mean that when my view goes to draw itself again, it's all mangled, as if it rememebers things like where I last moved something to

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to check out CGContextSaveGState(context) and CGContextRestoreGState(context). They will let you push and pop the current state of the context.

If your view is getting 'mangled', check your view's contentMode setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));`

Comment: This fills the context with a clear color, but does not reset any context state information (such as clipping, etc.)